DynamoDB partitions calculation
My DynamoDb table has 3000 rcu and 1000 wcu, the data size is well below 10 GB. Based on the formula to calculate partitions, 2 partitions will be created. I don't understand why 2 partitions are created but not one ?? Since the required rcu and wcu can be handled by one partition. Please anyone explain.
I tried to find an answer online, but so far I've got nothing

Sometimes you get a bit more than the bare minimum you need.
Partitions and their capabilities are an internal detail, and how many you get for different throughput specifications is subject to change. What’s required is that you get access to the throughput you’re requesting. You are.
Consider it the Bakers Dozen of DynamoDB.

It used to be that the number of partitions was determined by the formula #partitions = (wcu + rcu / 3) / 1000 (the 1000 WCU limit and the 3000 RCU limit are mutually exclusive). Based on this formula, plugging your numbers you get: #partitions = (1000 + 3000 / 3) / 1000 = 2000 / 2 = 2
That being said, DynamoDB has released many improvements to partitioning and rate limiting since the early days (pre 2018/2019) which may affect the above. For example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/
How did you determine that your table has 2 partitions? This is not something that is exposed directly. And in fact your table might even have more than two partitions, based on how it was configured and how provisioned capacity has changed over time.

I think, I have figured out why 2 partitions are needed and not 1. One partition can deliver either 3000 rcu or 1000 wcu or mix of both (i.e. if it has 500 wcu it can have 1500 rcu). It is not possible for a partition to deliver both 3000 rcu and 1000 wcu. By this logic, if one partition delivers all the required 3000 rcu, one more partiton is required to deliver 1000 wcu. Since they are distributed equally among partitons, each partition will deliver 1500 rcu and 500 wcu.

This has been explained here
